# Drowsy dataset for training the neural network

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, training-data

I am trying to build a tensorflow classifier for which I need a drowsy dataset. Is there any available drowsy dataset which can be used for my training set?

Comment: Something like http://cv.cs.nthu.edu.tw/php/callforpaper/datasets/DDD/?

Comment: @thertweck I have mailed them very long ago but haven't got any reply from their side.

Comment: @Momin: sure I will go through it